# IIS Application pool private memory varies during startup

Tags: iis, application-pool

We run a Dot.Net MVC website and we have problems with application pool private memory settings in IIS.

Our host provider has set application pool's Private Memory Limit it to 1GByte and it crashes constantly after some minutes, as it far exceeds this limit (2,4 GByte). They had the kindness to share with us their application pool settings.

We configure our local IIS application pool to the same settings, private memory 1024000 Kbytes.

We run several tests with that settings. In our environment, the private memory that w3wp.exe consumes varies from 1,2 GByte to 700 Kbytes at startup and after that and then lowers about 450 to 600 KBytes even when we run a stress test against it with more than 50 simultaneous users. As the number of users increases, the private memory is lowered, even to 400 Kbytes.

My question is: why are there so many differences?

Comment: Ask your host provider for process dump files and analyze them. That's the most intuitive way to tell the differences. Often you need to open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com if you are not capable of such analysis.

Comment: Sure, I will ask them for dump files, thanks for your suggestion, but if anyone has faced the same problem and have some idea he's answer is welcomed.